# How to extract all property-access statements from an expression in C#?

Tags: c#, lambda, properties, expression

I've implemented an command-condition mechanism for C#/WPF, which automates motoring, whether a specific action may be executed or not. Just for sake of explaining motives of the question, here's a simple example.

```
this.DocumentExistsCondition = new Condition(false);
this.SaveDocumentCommand = new AppCommand(() => DoSaveDocument, DocumentExistsCondition);
```

Then I may just change the condition like:

```
this.DocumentExistsCondition.Value = false;
```

So that all dependent commands change their availability. The mechanism is complex, allows aggregating conditions, and-ing and or-ing them etc.

One of condition types allows user to specify a member-of-member and watch its value, like:

```
documentExistsCondition = new MutablePropertyNotNullCondition<DocumentsManager, BaseDocumentViewModel>(documentsManager, dm => dm.ActiveDocument);
```

This simplifies things even further, because I no longer have to actively track the property, this condition implementation does that for me.

My mechanism is quite limited though, because expression specified as second parameter *must* be a property-access-statement. That's because I'm extracting property name, checking if source instance implements INotifyPropertyChange and then hook for this specific property changes.

I'd like to extend this mechanism and allow user to provide any expressions that evaluate to some object, but use a single property from the source, ie.

```
documentExistsCondition = new MutablePropertyNotNullCondition<DocumentsManager, BaseDocumentViewModel>(documentsManager, dm => dm.ActiveDocument != null ? dm.ActiveDocument : BaseDocumentViewModel.Default);
```

The way I'm currently extracting the property is the following:

```
private PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo<TClass, TClassProperty>(Expression<Func<TClass, TClassProperty>> propertyLambda)
{
    Type type = typeof(TClass);

    var member = propertyLambda.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (member == null)
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
            "Expression '{0}' refers to a method, not a property.",
            propertyLambda.ToString()));

    var propInfo = member.Member as PropertyInfo;
    if (propInfo == null)
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
            "Expression '{0}' refers to a field, not a property.",
            propertyLambda.ToString()));

    if (type != propInfo.ReflectedType &&
        !type.IsSubclassOf(propInfo.ReflectedType))
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
            "Expression '{0}' refers to a property that is not from type {1}.",
            propertyLambda.ToString(),
            type));

    return propInfo;
}
```

Is there a way to simply extract a list of all property-access statements from a complex statement? Or do I have to recursively go through all kinds of expressions and do it manually?

To say in different words: can I traverse the statement tree on some general level (like `foreach var childStatement in ChildStatements) { ... }`)?

Comment: Note that lambda *expressions* (i.e. the sort created from the lambda syntax) are not, and cannot contain, statements. What exactly do you mean by "child statements"?

Comment: @canton7, I expressed myself incorrectly, I mean, "X.Prop != null ? X.Prop : 5"  is an example. The expression tree will include the comparison, trinary operator and two member-accesses. My aim is to process the whole expression automatically and get only the member-accesses (and then process them)

Comment: Aha. Use an `ExpressionVisitor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use an [`ExpressionVisitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor) for this:

```
public class MemberExpressionRecorder : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public List<MemberExpression> MemberExpressions { get; } = new List<MemberExpression>();

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        MemberExpressions.Add(node);
        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
}

...

var visitor = new MemberExpressionRecorder();
visitor.Visit(someExpression);
// access visitor.MemberExpressions
```